# Why does Regex.Replace leave parenthesis?

Tags: c#, regex

Lets say you have:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("people (MANY)", "(many)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then after this result will be `people ()`. Why is this and how do I alter the regex replace to remove the brackets too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx

The following characters have to be escaped in Regular Expressions because they have a meaning in pattern matching:

> . $ ^ { [ ( | ) * + ? \

You can escape this special chars with the backslash `\` in your case `\(` and `\)`

Your code changed accordingly:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("people (MANY)", "\(many\)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 4):

In regex there is a set of characters that can have a special meaning (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space), if you want them always represented in your pattern you need to escape them.

There is a general function [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will go through the above list and escape every instance it finds for you.

```
Regex.Escape("(many)") // this becomes \(many\)
```

Comment: Useful function to know about! Infact, just used it in my second code instance where the string to match is inside a variable already.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the parenthesis have a meaning in Regex patterns. They define a [capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Escape the parenthesis, so that they are not seen as special characters but as parenthesis:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("people (MANY)", @"\(many\)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to

```
string result = Regex.Replace("people (MANY)", @"\(many\)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The () mean something special to the regex engine, so you have to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are special characters for grouping, you need to escape them:

```
Regex.Replace("people (MANY)", @"\(many\)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis in a regex let you define a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You need to escape them for them to be considered as regular characters

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses have a special meaning in regexes -- they're for *capturing* (so in the replace you could use $1 and it would give you what was in the parens).  If you want a literal you have to escape them:  \(